# Create a list of objects that directly represents an Excel sheet

Tags: c#, dynamic, linq-to-excel

Using LinqToExcel, I'm trying to create a dynamic list of objects that have a dynamic number of properties (with values). Essentially, the list of objects should directly represent the contents of an Excel sheet. However, I don't know the header names or the number columns before hand.

The code below does not work, it doesn't even compile, but I'm hoping it will show what I'm trying to do. Also it is missing a way to loop and add the correct number of properties. The names and number of properties should come from an array of column headers `columnNameList` .

```
    // get the records
    var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(path);
    IEnumerable<string> columnNameList = excel.GetColumnNames(mod.SelectedSheet);
    var ExpandoObject = (from x in excel.Worksheet(selectedSheet)
                          select new ExpandoObject()
                          {
                              ExpandoObject.Prop1 = x["excelCol1"],
                              ExpandoObject.Prop2 = x["excelCol2"],
                              ExpandoObject.Prop3 = x["excelCol3"],
                              ExpandoObject.Prop4 = x["excelCol4"],
                              ExpandoObject.Prop5 = DateTime.Now
                          }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the LinqToExcel.Row class. Here's the section from the documentation that shares how to use it:

### Using the LinqToExcel.Row class

Query results can be returned as LinqToExcel.Row objects which allows you to access a cell's value by using the column name in the string index. Just use the `Worksheet()` method without a generic argument.

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory("excelFileName");
var indianaCompanies = from c in excel.Worksheet()
                       where c["State"] == "IN" || c["Zip"] == "46550"
                       select c;
```

The LinqToExcel.Row class allows you to easily cast a cell's value by using its `Cast<>()` method

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory("excelFileName");
var largeCompanies = from c in excel.Worksheet()
                     where c["EmployeeCount"].Cast<int>() > 500
                     select c;
```

Comment: I don't know the name of the Excel rows before hand see OP